# xslt to keep most recent entries grouped by key

Tags: date, xslt, group-by

I need to keep the most recent entries from an input xml grouping by a key value. Is it possible to do it with xsl 2.0?
Input

```
<root>
<line>
    <date>2021-01-01T00:00:00</date>
    <field1>AAA</field1>
    <field2>1</field2>
</line>
<line>
    <date>2021-01-01T23:00:00</date>
    <field1>BBB</field1>
    <field2>1</field2>
</line>
<line>
    <date>2021-01-02T00:00:00</date>
    <field1>CCC</field1>
    <field2>2</field2>
</line>
```

Output should be

```
<root>
<line>
    <date>2021-01-01T23:00:00</date>
    <field1>BBB</field1>
    <field2>1</field2>
</line>
<line>
    <date>2021-01-02T00:00:00</date>
    <field1>CCC</field1>
    <field2>2</field2>
</line>
```

The xsl keeps the most recent entry grouping by field2, so the result is two entries (field2= 1 and field2=2).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="root/line" group-by="field2">
        <xsl:sort select="date"/>
        <line>
            <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
        </line>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Where exactly are you stuck with this?

Comment: XSLT 2 and 3 grouping is shown in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info, sorting is done by processing the `current-group()` and using `xsl:sort` or you can just select the item in the `current-group()` with the `max(current-group()/date/xs:dateTime(.)) = xs:dateTime(date)`.

Comment: I've used the xsl updated in the question but is not working.

Comment: "not working" is not a good description of a problem. What is the actual result? And are you're your XSLT processor supports XSLT 2.0? Your stylesheet declares  `version="1.0"`.

Comment: It keeps 2 lines but the field1=AAA instead of BBB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt sorts the **groups**, not the lines within each group. It then copies the first node in each group.

To do this by sorting, you would need to do something like:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="line" group-by="field2">
            <xsl:variable name="sorted-group">
                <xsl:perform-sort select="current-group()">
                    <xsl:sort select="date" order="descending"/>
                </xsl:perform-sort>            
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$sorted-group/line[1]"/>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this copies only the **first** line in descending date order. If there are two lines that have the same date, only the first one of these (in document order) will be copied to the output.

---

Alternatively you could select the lines that have the maximal dateTime within their group:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="line" group-by="field2">
            <xsl:variable name="max-dateTime" select="max(current-group()/date/xs:dateTime(.))" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[date=$max-dateTime]"/>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here a tie would be resolved by copying both lines.