# hot to retrieve and format a start and end date for multiple LOA on one person

Tags: xml, xslt, formatdatetime

I am trying to write XSLT for finding the start and end date of a persons Leave of absence then formatting it. The persons xml I'm using has two different LOA sections. I am having trouble getting the oldest of the start dates and the most recent leave end date and then formatting them. Getting errors like to many arguments. I'm sure it's something simple but I can't seem to get it.

```
<LOA_Start_Date xtt:fixedLength="8">
    <xsl:if test="ws:Status/ws:Employee_Status = 'On_Leave'">
        <xsl:value-of select="ws:Leave_of_Absence = ws:On_Leave['true']"/>
    </xsl:if>  
    <xsl:then>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-date(min(ws:Leave_Start_Date, '[Y0001][M01][D01]'))"/>
    </xsl:then>
</LOA_Start_Date>



<LOA_End_Date xtt:fixedLength="8">
    <xsl:if test="ws:Status/ws:Employee_Status = 'Return_From_Leave'">
        <xsl:value-of select="ws:Leave_of_Absence = ws:On_Leave['false']"/>
    </xsl:if>  
    <xsl:then>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-date(max(ws:Leave_End_Date, '[Y0001][M01][D01]'))"/>
    </xsl:then>
</LOA_End_Date>


XML section:
<ws:Leave_of_Absence>
            <ws:On_Leave>true</ws:On_Leave>
            <ws:Leave_Start_Date>2022-10-27</ws:Leave_Start_Date>         
        </ws:Leave_of_Absence>
        <ws:Leave_of_Absence>
            <ws:On_Leave>false</ws:On_Leave>
            <ws:Leave_Start_Date>2022-10-24</ws:Leave_Start_Date>
            <ws:Leave_End_Date>2022-10-27</ws:Leave_End_Date>
        </ws:Leave_of_Absence>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve], not snippets of code taken out of context. Also state which version of XSLT your processor supports.

Comment: it's version 2.0

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67907822/3016153

Answer (score 0):

Call `max` on a sequence of `xs:date` values e.g. `max(.//ws:Leave_End_Date/xs:date(.))`. You can pass the max value at the `format-date` function.